# Different result from OpenCV sample code?

Tags: c++, opencv, surf

I'm trying [this](http://docs.opencv.org/3.1.0/d5/d6f/tutorial_feature_flann_matcher.html) code about SURF keypoints matching, this should be the result:

[image]

However, this is my result:

[image]

As you can see, in my case there are only 6 matches against >15 in the original example. Why this happens?

I've installed OpenCV 3.1 and of course opencv_contrib.

Comment: "Why this happens?" Because presumably the example is old or there's a regression. This should be reported to OpenCV as a bug instead, because there isn't much to say besides the expected result either being wrong (very unlikely), code being wrong (very unlikely) or there being a regression (likely).

Comment: @tambre What do you mean by "regression"?

Comment: You know, regression, kind of a bug type. It worked before, we changed something, now it doesn't, but it should, thus we conclude it *regressed*. There's *regression* in such a case. Google is your friend. See [Software regression](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Software_regression). Remember, Google is your friend.

Comment: Or maybe you're not using the same images (e.g. yours are smaller).

Comment: @AdiShavit I'm using the images given in samples/data

Comment: Maybe they were changed since the tutorial was made? Don't know. Try checking out an older branch.